# Attempt to read property "nama_jabatan" on int - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 4 models for my project.

Karyawan
Role
Jabatan
Divisi

This is how I call the view:

```
https://codeshare.io/xvYz4B
```

and this is my model view on Karyawan:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Cuti;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Divisi;
use App\Models\Jabatan;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Karyawan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['karyawan_id'];
    protected $table = 'karyawans';

    public function scopeSearch($query, array $searchs) {

        $query->when($searchs['search'] ?? false, function($query, $search) {
            return $query->where('nama', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('divisi', 'like', '%' . $search . '%') 
            ->orWhere('jabatan', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('agama', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('nik', 'like', '%' . $search . '%'); 
        });
    }

    public function role_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    public function divisi()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Divisi::class);
    }

    public function jabatan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Jabatan::class);
    }

    public function cuti()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cuti::class);
    }
```

but it keeps getting error "Attempt to read property "nama_jabatan" on int". All I want is to display the name of "Jabatan" based on the ID.

Thank you before.

Answer (score 0):

In your view change line
`$kar->jabatan_id->nama_jabatan`
To

$kar->jabatan->nama_jabatan

Comment: it comes to an error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jabatans.id' in 'where clause'

select * from `jabatans` where `jabatans`.`id` = 3 limit 1


do you think I made mistake on eloquent relationship on models?